# Add 'and' before the last item in a string list

Tags: python, string, list, join

Okay so I'm trying to make a function that will take a list of items and return (not print!) a string of that list, separated by commas with an 'and' before the last item in the list. My script so far looks like this:

```
rose1 = Thing("red rose", "flowerbox")
rose2 = Thing("pink rose","garden")
rose3 = Thing("white rose", "vase")

def text_list(things):
    """Takes a sequence of Things and returns a formatted string that describes all of the things.

    Things -> string"""
    names=[o.name for o in things]
    if len(names) == 0:
        return 'nothing'
    elif len(names) == 2:
        names = ' and the '.join(names)
        return 'the ' + names
    else:   #Here's where I need help!
        names = ', the '.join(names)
        return 'the ' + names
```

So at this point the function returns "the red rose, the pink rose, the white rose" which is great, but I need that last "and" to be put in between the pink rose and the white rose, and I can't use print. Any help? This is probably simple and I'm just missing it entirely OTL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if the following suffices your requirement.

```
names=[o.name for o in things[:-1]]
last_name = things[-1].name
```

use your logic for 'names' list to get `result_string` and finally append last_name to the string.

```
return result_string + ' and the ' + last_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a single line:

```
print(', '.join([*lst[:-1], f'and {lst[-1]}']))
```

For example:

```
a_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
print(', '.join([*a_list[:-1], f'and {a_list[-1]}']))
```

This produces the result

```
a, b, and c
```

This will of course won't give the desired results if the list consists of a single item or the empty list.

Comment: `f = lambda x: ' and '.join([', '.join(x[:-1]),x[-1]]) if len(x) > 1 else x[0] if len(x) > 0 else ''`

Comment: The original post was asking about a function, not printing tricks. With that in mind, your answer has a hidden potential bug - a missing space before the word "and" which are automatically added by the `print` function.